# Is it possible to have an F# operator overload, on an internal type, available to all files in the assembly?

Tags: f#

I have some types that enforce numeric value ranges, and I use them in many files in a single project.  They look something like this:

```ml
[<Struct>]
type NonNegativeMoney =
    new(x) =
        if x < 0m then invalidArg "x" "Ruh-roh..."
        { Value = x }
    val Value : decimal
    static member (+) (x: NonNegativeMoney, y: NonNegativeMoney) = NonNegativeMoney(x.Value + y.Value)
```

I now want to make these types internal to the assembly and leave only my OO type model public.  However, when I flip these types to internal, I got the following compiler error:

> The member or object constructor 'op_Addition' is not public. Private
>   members may only be accessed from within the declaring type. Protected
>   members may only be accessed from an extending type and cannot be
>   accessed from inner lambda expressions.

The reason for this, has been addressed in the question [Why does the F# compiler fail with this infix operator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17475607/why-does-the-f-compiler-fail-with-this-infix-operator).  The solution proposed in the answer is to use [F# signature files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/signature-files) to make the types internal.  This works for the OP's scenario in that question, where usage of the operator is limited to a type in the same file.  However, I can't seem to find a way to make it work so the operator is accessible from all files in my project.  If I use a signature file, it works intra-file, but not inter-file.

Is there any way to make this work so the types are internal to the assembly, but visible across the files in my project?  I'd like to keep the operators, as I'm using library functions like `Seq.sum` that require them on the types being summed.

Comment: Have you tried annotating it with the `InternalsVisibleTo` attribute?

Comment: @s952163 what would I annotate? I thought `InternalsVisibleTo` was for inter-assembly usage.  I'm trying to use the operator from within the same assembly. Please could you elaborate?

Comment: I see. You would annotate the assembly attribute, sg. like this `[<assembly: InternalsVisibleTo("NonNegativeMoney")>], you could try it but as you say your use case is slightly different.

Comment: The `InternalsVisibleTo` attribute takes an assembly name in the constructor, so don't think I can use `NonNegativeMoney`.  Maybe I could pull the numeric typesinto a new assembly, use signature files to make things internal (as per the other answer) and then add the `InternalsVisibileTo` attribute, citing my main assembly.  Feels pretty dirty though.  Hoping there is a better way.

Comment: The solution I proposed in my previous comment, still does not work for the operators.  I moved the types to new assembly, added sig files (to make internal) and then used `InternalsVisibleTo` but I now get `BlahBlahType.fs(10, 10): [FS0001] The member or object constructor 'op_Addition' is not public. Private members may only be accessed from within the declaring type. Protected members may only be accessed from an extending type and cannot be accessed from inner lambda expressions.`  I can create values of the type (so I know IVT is working), but the op usage still fails.

Answer (score 0):

You can define the overload in a module instead of inside the type:

```
[<Struct>]
type internal NonNegativeMoney =
    new(x) =
        if x < 0m then invalidArg "x" "Ruh-roh..."
        { Value = x }
    val Value : decimal

let internal (+) (x: NonNegativeMoney) (y: NonNegativeMoney) = NonNegativeMoney(x.Value + y.Value)
```

...but this will override the normal (+) operator, which is probably why you ruled it out. Using a custom operator (like ++) may be a reasonable compromise.

You can make the operator available to the whole project by marking the module `[<AutoOpen>]`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  I hadn't actually considered doing this, but I don't think it solves my problem, because I'm using library functions like `sum` and `sumBy` which require `op_Addition` on the type.  I'll edit the question to include that detail.