# F# - Unexpected behaviour in operator overloading

Tags: f#

The following F# code compiles successfully:

```
namespace MyNamespace

module Module = 
    type T = 
        static member (*) (t1: T, t2: T): T = Unchecked.defaultof<T>

    type U = 
        member __.Method(t1: T, t2: T) = t1 * t2
```

However, if a private qualifier is added to Module, an error is generated:

```
namespace MyNamespace

module private Module = 
    type T = 
        static member (*) (t1: T, t2: T): T = Unchecked.defaultof<T>

    type U = 
        member __.Method(t1: T, t2: T) = t1 * t2 //error
```

> Error FS0043  The member or object constructor 'op_Multiply' is not
> public. Private members may only be accessed from within the declaring
> type. Protected members may only be accessed from an extending type
> and cannot be accessed from inner lambda expressions.

This error doesn't sound right:

- It says that the operator is not public, but technically it is at class level.
- If a static method is used in place of the (*) operator, no errors.

?

Comment: That's interesting. Seems like a bug to me. I couldn't find an existing issue that describes this, so you might want to [create one](https://github.com/dotnet/fsharp/issues).

Answer (score 0):

Upon a bit of searching, this appears to at least be known behavior (to a small few) with a poor error message and an existing language suggestion.

This F# issue https://github.com/dotnet/fsharp/issues/1956 points to the language suggestion https://github.com/fsharp/fslang-suggestions/issues/230.

As to why this occurs, Don Syme mentions in the above links:

> "private" on a type in F# means "private to the enclosing namespace declaration group or module".

> However right now all solutions to statically resolved calls must currently be public. There's an open language suggestion to lift that limitation, in which case this code would indeed compile.

---

Here are some related StackOverflow questions I happened to find while searching:

- [Why does the F# compiler fail with this infix operator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17475607/why-does-the-f-compiler-fail-with-this-infix-operator)
- [Is it possible to have an F# operator overload, on an internal type, available to all files in the assembly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52514687/is-it-possible-to-have-an-f-operator-overload-on-an-internal-type-available-t)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/34682551)

Comment: It isn't too clear what else you think should be included though. The answer is "This is known behavior, and there is a language suggestion for it.", which is what my answer says.

Comment: Looks fine now.